# Character-length of a text in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a TextBlock component in a WPF project. The content of the text is set from an RSS feed that is usually longer that that can be displayed in the text box. How can I find out how many character may exist in my TextBlock component? I would also like to find out how much text is displayed to the user.

I tried to create my own TextTrimming-Method. I would have to know how much text is present in a label or a text block can be entered, so I can cut my string at the appropriate place.

Maybe everyone knows how the TextTrimming-Method works an can tell me!

Comment: Why not use a readonly TextBox which can have scrollbars when the text overflows?

Comment: @Matapolo - I tried to tidy up the English in your post. If this has altered the meaning of the question in anyway, please feel free to revert back to your original question.

Also, I could not figure out what you meant in the second paragraph to rephrase it.

Comment: It´s for a newsside. For every news, thera a two lines. On the End of this Lines I will trim the text and insert a linkButton, which send the user to a website with all information.

Answer (score 0):

Read the RSS feed into a string in code-behind file and then get the length

Comment: and how do I know how much character to fit into my TextBlock?

Answer (score 0):

Why we developers, as a whole, feel the need to reinvent the wheel?

Why not simply try:

```
<Label MaxWidth="100"> 
  <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi 
    non orci tortor. Aenean commodo urna quis lacus convallis sit amet 
    tempor neque dictum. Nam aliquet pretium commodo. Nam tellus 
    velit, cursus a vulputate at, viverra sit amet mauris. 
  </TextBlock>
</Label>
```